# Unable to Group by Parent in Stacked bar chart - ADO Dashboard widget

Tags: azure-devops, widget, dashboard, ado

I have been trying to group by parent in Stacked bar graph. Parent field doesn't appear on the group by list. Is it not possible to group by parent? Any other alternatives?

Tried to create a custom filed with parent info. But this is an additional work for those create work item

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not supported to group by `parent` in Stacked bar currently.

As per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/charts?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fqueries%2Ftoc.json&%3Bbc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fqueries%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#create-a-query-based-chart), users can add the field in the query column so that the field will be listed in the chart dropdown list.

[image]

For example, add `Iteration Path` and custom field `field2` in query column, save, they will appear in the chart dropdown list, but `parent` will NOT be listed.

[image]

As a workaround, you could use the `custom field` which has same value with `parent`, and group by the `custom field` in the chart instead.

[image]

I totally understand your query, you can raise a user voice ticket to link [here](https://aka.ms/AzDevOpsIdeas) to add or fix it, thanks.